# Queries about Ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to install Ubuntu touch on my Nexus 4 but , before installing i want to know that whether the basic applications can be installed on it , like twitter ,  Google maps , banking apps and others , what is the average battery life i would get after installing Ubuntu touch.Does it have any network issues.

Answer (score 0):

The most major apps are available like Twitter, Facebook or Google Maps.
The average battery lifetime are 2-3 days.
Network functions (WLAN) running fine including daily updates (depends on your image).
But remember, everything is in a developing state.